# I have `c(1,2,3)` and `c(4,5,6)`, how can I get a `list(1:4,2:5,3:6)` or similar thing?

Tags: r, list, vector, vectorization

I've tried

```r
c(1,2,3):c(4,5,6)
```

and it errors duly. and

```r
list(1,2,3):list(4,5,6)
```

errors also.

I want get the answer with simply and quicker (means vectorization maybe ...) way.

The aim I want should equal with

```r
list (1:4, 2:5, 3:6)
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: `Map(seq, c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6))`

Comment: Similar: `Map(\`:\`, x, y)`